# How to open Digital surface model (DSM) image?

Tags: image, matlab, surface

I have a Digital Surface Model (DSM) Image. I tried to open it with imread() from image processing toolbox but it only shows me a white image. when I open the matrix of image I found the that the arrays have values but dont show anything.
Anyone can help me?

Comment: First of all: I have never seen DSM Image file and do not know about the format. What does your resulting matrix look like? Does it have the expected dimensions? How do you display your data? Can you provide an example file?

Comment: how do you show it? `imshow(img,[])` or `imshow(img)`? try the former

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DSM is not a format supported by MATLAB. Here is the list of formats:
http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/supported-file-formats.html

You can try converting the image to a supported MATLAB format using online converters or software like IrfanView, provided that a format change will not alter the image properties for your purpose.